# GPPSignIn Not Refreshing Token After 1 Hour in iOS

Tags: ios, google-analytics, google-plus

I am using the GPPSignIn class to log in to G+ as per

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in#automatically_sign_in_the_user

It all works fine until the token expires an hour later, at which point the [[GPPSignin  sharedInstance] trySilentAuthentication] returns that it is successful, but the access token associated with the auth does not appear to renew (I'm using it to access the Google Analytics API) and my calls to the analytics api then stop working. If the app starts from scratch things work fine again.

Anyone else have issues with tokens expiring?